# How to create a function for cloning an element that can be used multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have created a jQuery function which clones a field (or set of fields) in case the user likes to add additional data. For example, there is just one **Speaker Name** field. But if there are 2 or more, the user clicks a button "Add More Speaker" and another field will show up.

However, how do I edit the function in such a way that I can use this multiple times within a page for different fields that needs to be duplicated (say, I also have "Add More Guest"). If I use the same classes, all will get triggered no matter which set that button belongs to.

E.g. Clicking on "Add More Speaker" will also clone fields for "Add More Guest".

**HTML:**

```
<label>Form Label</label>
<div class="j-field">
  <div class="j-field-set">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="" class="j-add-field"> Add Form Field</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function cloneOption(cloneTrigger, cloneObject, cloneObjectParent) {
  $(cloneTrigger).click(function(e) {
    $(cloneObject).first().clone().appendTo(cloneObjectParent);
    e.preventDefault();
  });  
}

cloneOption(".j-add-field",".j-field-set",".j-field");
```

Comment: Just call `cloneOption` multiple times with different classes?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You need to restructure it as a jQuery plugin, which will store state information on the `data` of a jQuery target element. Then you will be able to write  code like `$('form').cloneMe(options)` to attach it to all forms on the page separately. Google "writing jQuery plugins" or similar. There are several simple patterns (I use a single TypeScript base class for all my plugins, so my code will not be useful to you).

Comment: @Bergi I thought so too but just thinking if there's a more compact way since essentially, they're doing the same thing. Like for the buttons to target the closest set to them or something, if that's even possible.

Comment: @catandmouse: You mean you want to avoid that `cloneObjectParent` parameter and determine the target dynamically? But no, I think you still will need to use different classes to distinguish buttons and fieldsets in different groups. Or is there some structure-based link? You've shown too less of your markup.